# Вычесть n часов из date()

Tags: дата, php

```
date('d.m.Y H:i', $timestamp);
```

Как вычесть например 3 часа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если у вас $timestamp - в формате UNIX, то проще некуда

```
$timestamp-3*60*60
```

Comment: @Ale_x, ох :) Что-то я совсем.. ) Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Ale_x, а если не UNIX формат, а просто функция time(), мне нужно от текущего времени отнять 12 часов. Пробовал вашим способом не помогло.

Answer (score 3):

**time**

```
$time = time() - 3 * 60 * 60; // секунды
echo date('d.m.Y H:i', $time);
```

**strtotime**

```
$time = strtotime('-3 hours');
echo date('d.m.Y H:i', $time);
```

**DateTime**

```
$date = new \DateTime('-3 hours');
echo $date->format('d.m.Y H:i');
```